# Почему возникает ошибка: Exception: You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById?

Tags: google-apps-script

Это возможно слишком "чайный" вопрос:
Есть код:

```
function AAA1() {
  var s =2,
      s2 =4,
      s3 =5;
 var spreadsheet_id = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId();
 var sheet_name = "Лист1";

 return(s+s2+s3);
}
```

Он рабочий. Результат при вызове функции корректный. 
Я добавляю еще одну переменную:

```
var s4 = SpreadsheetApp.openById( spreadsheet_id ).getSheetByName( sheet_name ).getRange(1,1).getValues(); // это строка №7
```

В Logger.log(s4); результат отображается правильно.
Но сам вызов процедуры дает ошибку:
*Ошибка:
Exception: You do not have permission 
to call SpreadsheetApp.openById. 
Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets (строка 7)*

---

**Вопрос**: введение в код новой переменной может давать ошибку?
Или ошибка в другом?

Comment: В тексте ошибки написано в чем заключается ошибка.

Comment: :-)) Вот поэтому я и спросила, разве добавление переменной может запретить вызов функции. И если да, то почему? Как то в других языках, в том же VBA например, это нормально.

Comment: У вас нет права на выполнение функции, причем тут добавление переменной? Вы добавили не только переменную, но и кучу других вещей, в числе которых и вызов функции, на которую у вас нет прав.

Comment: Благодарю. Постараюсь разбираться дальше.

Comment: Вы вызываете функцию как формулу?

Comment: Да, вызываю ее как формулу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если коротко, то так сделать нельзя.

Скорее всего проблема в том, что функция вызывается как пользовательская функция.

В сущности, вопрос стоит внимания, потому что он является общим случаем недопонимания процесса.

И так, куда смотреть и что делать.

Способ запуска. От способа запуска зависит многое, т.к. один и тот же код может выполняться по-разному. Называется "смена контекста".

- Как пользовательская формула (специальный ограниченный контекст)
- При вызове из редактора (основной контекст)
- При вызове из UI контейнера (расширенный основной контекст)
- При вызове из триггера
- При вызове из неустановленного дополнения
- При вызове из неразрешенного дополнения
- При вызове из опубликованного веб-приложения
- При вызове опубликованного API
- И еще много чего можно сменить настройками для одного и того же куска (простите) кода.

Распространенной ошибкой является предполагать, что код в редакторе какой-то не такой. На самом деле это уже полноценное приложение. Многие, кто активно использует скрипты, "не парятся" на тему "откуда это запустить", они просто выбирают в редакторе функцию и жмут кнопку запуска.

Вернемся к баранам. **При запуске пользовательской формулы** контекст кода строго ограничен. **Вы не можете вызывать** многие методы `SpreadsheetApp`, например, `openById()`. См. [Custom Functions - Advanced - Using Apps Script services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_apps_script_services)

Интересно, что это не означает, что так делать нельзя. Например, хак описан тут [snippets/spreadsheet-get_error_value_formulas](https://github.com/contributorpw/google-apps-script-snippets/blob/c9e3b5c9ae19a3b94e6289c6f6b9a563f548667c/snippets/spreadsheet-get_error_value_formulas/get_error_value_formulas.js). Но это прям надо хорошо вкурить, чтоб оно взлетело.

Comment: Благодарю за очень полный и полезный комментарий.

Comment: @Aliona, можете отметить как решение

Comment: еще раз спасибо